# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, struts2, model-driven

This is my code of SQL Connection class where I am getting error.

```
public class SqlConnection {
    static Connection con;
.......

    static public ResultSet getData(String sql, List<LogModel> alist)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        if (alist != null) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= alist.size(); i++) {
                pst.setObject(i, alist.get(i-1)); //Exception at this Line
            }
        }
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Here is the `LogAction` class where i am calling this `getdata()` function.

```
public class LogAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<LogModel>, Preparable {

    LogModel log = null;
    List<LogModel> alist = null;
    public static final String FAILURE = "failure";

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        log = new LogModel();
        alist = new ArrayList<LogModel>();
    }

    @Override
    public LogModel getModel() {
        return log;
    }

    public String login() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String sql = "Select username,password from registration where username=? and password=?";
        alist.add(log);
        System.out.println(alist);
        ResultSet rs = SqlConnection.getData(sql, alist);
        if (rs.next()) {
            return SUCCESS;
        } else
            return FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: * ModelDriven<LogModel> is there

Comment: can we have the stack trace? This exception is thrown when the program tries to serialze an object of a class that does not implement `Serializable`

Comment: Is `LogModel` serializable?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson nope

Comment: I have did this thing without Generics then it works fine...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Now after making LogModel serialize, I am getting this Exception 'java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify  your code to

```
static public ResultSet getData(String sql, String username, String password)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, username);
    pst.setString(2, password);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    return rs;
}
```

setting model object to the parameter of the prepared statement makes non sense.

Comment: By using this I can't use this method for other queries.

Comment: @manindersingh I don't know what other queries, you didn't posted.

Comment: I want to use the getData() as universal method for LogAction class.

Comment: How is it universal if you want to set the not primitive object to the query then you need a persistence layer like hibernate. You can't make it universal because of different sql queries, use DAO pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the PreparedStatement has no idea how to setObject on your LogModel.  My advice would be to decompose that into SQL primitives so it'll know what to do with it.

Your code needs a lot of work.  You aren't closing JDBC resources properly.  Your LogAction class makes no sense.  Lots wrong with this little bit of code.  I'd be worried about your app.

Comment: When I used List instead of List<LogModel> and alist.add(log.getUsername), alist.add(log.getPassword) instead of alist.add(log) then everything works fine.