# Can a serialization problem in tomcat mix up user sessions?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, serialization, struts2

I have a Tomcat 7 server that was forcefully restarted today. Upon restart, users HTTP sessions got mixed up.

User A reported that after refreshing the webpage, User B data was shown instead of his own data. This is a severe problem.

Analyzing the logs, I found that Tomcat had problems writing HTTP session attributes:

```
Aug 08, 2019 11:47:16 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession writeObject
WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute MY_ATTRIBUTE for session 61504204C7A2904C981E2D37053138E6
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.model.MyClass
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
(...)

Aug 08, 2019 11:47:16 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession writeObject
WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute KEY for session C76DE179F9EBC659A91FB68D63D6F7E9
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.model.OtherClass
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
(...)
```

These session attributes are managed using Struts 2.

I also noticed that both User A and User B were logged in the system at the time of failure / restart.

I currently disabled session persistence in Tomcat, but I'm hopping that you could shed some light on the root cause of this problem.

I.e. What is the reason why Tomcat mixed up user sessions? Implementing Serializable interface will solve this problem? How can I be sure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tomcat shouldn't mix your sessions up, even if there are errors serializing certain attribute values. Are you using container-managed authentication and is Tomcat generating your sessions, cookies, etc? How is your application determining which "data" to show to each user? Can you reproduce this and show that data "moves" from session to session? Or that somehow one client's session can access another user's session?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213423/573032

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies and comments.

I found that my problem was a bug in my login service (as according to what I found online, is the most likely case when something like this this happens).

The login service had an instance variable containing information of the user that was about to login and, due to Spring configuration, this service was singleton. Whenever two users tried to login exactly at the same time, then this session mix up could happen.